# Feedback on closed question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

So a question of mine was closed.

[Probability distribution for the momentum of a particle undergoing a collision?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761400/)

I thought it was decently written (post the edits) however I guess it's still not up to standard. From a learning perspective can I have some feedback?

Comment: Generally, questions along the lines of ‘am I right’ or ‘is this right’ are not good fits, being taken as being homework-like. Now, I look at it as a scattering problem, but you have not indicated your interaction potential. Hard sphere vs Rutherford scattering come up with quite different results, for example. And one would not really set up the problem that way (or I would not).

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I was thinking of this more in light of kinetic gas theory. I didn't think of it as scattering if it explicitly depended on the potential I'd have to worry about it changing Maxwell distribution.